# Special character to have integer seen as a title/word, rather than an integer?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to use an integer as a feild for a table in one of my alloc inits but it give me an error (invalid suffix on floating constant). Is there a special character I put in front of the number so that it is seen as more of a 'title' for the feild?

Ex:

```
PREshapes *1234b = [[PREshapes alloc] init];
1234b.preName = @"1234b";
```

....error says 'invalid suffix 'b.preShape' on floating constant...but really I just want 1234b to be the title of a feild in a table.

I must be researching this with incorrect terminology becuase it shouldn't be this difficult to find.. thank you!

Comment: `1234b` isn't a valid c++ symbol.

Comment: Yes, the special character is any alphabet character (variable names cannot start with numbers in most languages).

Comment: if you change 1234b to b1234 it will compile

Comment: As always get a book on the language you are using and study it. A basic "C" language book is a good starting point.